# wrong use of _?NumberQ?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I am having trouble with a numerical exercise. Here's a simplified version of my problem.

I define two functions to find the solution to two constrained maximization problems:

```
g[a_,b_,x_]:=NArgMax[{h2[a,b,x,y], CONSTRAINT[a,b,x,y]},{y}][[1]]
f[a_,b_,y_]:=NArgMax[{h1[a,b,x,y], CONSTRAINT[a,b,x,y]},{x}][[1]]
```

In the above definitions h1(.) and h2(.) are "well-behaved" objective functions, "a" and "b" are parameters and `CONSTRAINT[a,b,x,y]` is a given inequality involving the parameters and choice variables.

With these functions, I would like to find a fixed point, say, `xstar`:

```
FindRoot[{xstar==f[a, b, g[a,b,xstar] ]}, {xstar, 0}]
```

When I try to run `FindRoot` with actual numbers for "a" and "b" I get an error saying that the constraint in the maximization problem is not valid. I think the problem is that it attempts to make a symbolic evaluation. I hence tried defining the functions as `g[a_,b_,x_?NumberQ]` and `f[a_,b_,x_?NumberQ]`, but it didn't work.

However, when I defined:

```
G[x_?NumberQ]:=g[a,b,x]
F[y_?NumberQ]:=f[a,b,y]
```

and then fixed values for the parameters by setting them equal to a given number (e.g. `a=b=0.1`),then it did work.

It seems then that I am doing something wrong when I use `?NumberQ` in the original function to avoid symbolic evaluation... Any ideas on why it is wrong and how to solve it?

I would like to make a plot for different values of "a" and "b", so running the simulations one by one (as in the solution I mention above that works, by redefining the function only in terms of one variable) is extremely inefficient... and I'm sure there's a smarter way of doing it ! ;)

**Here is a complete example using the above notation**:

```
h1[a_, b_, x_, y_] := PDF[BinormalDistribution[{a, b}, {1, 1}, .5], {x, y}]
h2[a_, b_, x_, y_] := PDF[BinormalDistribution[{a, b}, {.5, .5}, .7], {x, y}]
CONSTRAINT[a_, b_, x_, y_] := CDF[BinormalDistribution[{a, b}, {1, 1}, .5], {x, y}]
g[a_, b_, x_] := NArgMax[{h2[a, b, x, y], CONSTRAINT[a, b, x, y] < .5}, {y}][[1]]
f[a_, b_, y_] := NArgMax[{h1[a, b, x, y], CONSTRAINT[a, b, x, y] < .5}, {x}][[1]]

FindRoot[{xstar == f[1, 1, g[1, 1, xstar]]}, {xstar, 0}]
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `NumberQ` with `NumericQ`?

Comment: ...same error message

Comment: The problem is your `CONSTRAINT` because functions like `NArgMax`, `FindMinimum`, ... really like to have *explicit* (in)equalities there. Can your `CONSTRAINS` be evaluated without numerical values? Then `NArgMax[Evaluate@{h2[a,b,x,y], CONSTRAINT[a,b,x,y]},{y}]` might help.

Comment: @EOO Can you maybe give a **small**, complete example?

Comment: Thanks, yes; the problem is that the constraint is nonalgebraic. I edited the question above and included a complete example at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we found out in the comments, your original error message came from `CONSTRAINT` not being an (in)equality. After changing this and adding `?NumericQ` to your functions, you can easily (but slowly) create a table of your roots depending on `a`

```
h1[a_, b_, x_, y_] := PDF[BinormalDistribution[{a, b}, {1, 1}, .5], {x, y}]
h2[a_, b_, x_, y_] := PDF[BinormalDistribution[{a, b}, {.5, .5}, .7], {x, y}]
CONSTRAINT[a_, b_, x_, y_] := CDF[BinormalDistribution[{a, b}, {1, 1}, .5], {x, y}]
g[a_, b_, x_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[{h2[a, b, x, y], CONSTRAINT[a, b, x, y] < .5}, {y}][[1]]
f[a_, b_, y_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[{h1[a, b, x, y], CONSTRAINT[a, b, x, y] < .5}, {x}][[1]]

data = Table[{a, xstar /. FindRoot[{xstar == f[a, 1, g[a, 1, xstar]]}, 
  {xstar, 0}]}, {a, .5, 1, .1}];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As your question was about `NumberQ`, let me point out that it makes in this example no difference whether you use `NumberQ` or `NumericQ`. One important thing about `NumberQ` is that for instance `NumberQ[Pi]` returns false. So if you define a *numerical* function with a `NumberQ` pattern, someone who calls your function with `Pi`, `Sqrt[2]`, etc will not get an answer. This is usually not wanted.

What you want to say in most cases is *the function can be used for arguments which can be transformed with `N` into a numerical expression*. This is what `NumericQ` does and therefore I would suggest to stick with it.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried what you suggest and it didn't work --in fact, when I copy/pasted your code and ran it, it didn't work at first... It turns out (I just realize) that the introduction of `?NumberQ` in the definition of the function has to be done on a clean function (it doesn't replace an existing definition). In the end, the solution is indeed to use `f[a_, b_, x_?NumericQ]` BUT clearing `f[]` beforehand (don't know if this is obvious but it cost me a lot of time).

Comment: @EOO It's ok, that you missed it. A common mistake and a lot people (including me) stumbled over this several times. The function definition is not overwritten, because you changed the call pattern. You could have checked `??f` to see all definitions.