# Assign FindRoot output vector to a vector instead of element by element

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, assignment

Using `FindRoot` to solve a multivariate equation system, assigning the output to variables one by one works, but assigning the output vector to a vector gives the error (MWE below) `SetDelayed::shape: Lists {xsola,ysola} and {x,y}/. FindRoot[{D[(x-1)^2]==0,D[(y-2)^2]==0},{{x,0.3},{y,0.4}}] are not the same shape.` The output of `FindRoot` is `{1., 2.}` and the list `{xsola,ysola}` prints as `{xsola,ysola}`. To me, these lists do look the same shape, but seemingly not to Mathematica.

How to assign a vector output of `FindRoot` to a vector?

MWE:

```
Clear[x, y, xsol, ysol, xsola, ysola]
xsol := x /. 
  FindRoot[{D[(x - 1)^2] == 0, 
    D[(y - 2)^2] == 0}, {{x, 0.3}, {y, 0.4}}]
ysol := y /. 
   FindRoot[{D[(x - 1)^2] == 0, 
    D[(y - 2)^2] == 0}, {{x, 0.3}, {y, 0.4}}]
{xsola, ysola} := {x, y} /. 
  FindRoot[{D[(x - 1)^2] == 0, 
    D[(y - 2)^2] == 0}, {{x, 0.3}, {y, 0.4}}]
{x, y} /. 
 FindRoot[{D[(x - 1)^2] == 0, D[(y - 2)^2] == 0}, {{x, 0.3}, {y, 0.4}}]
{xsola, ysola}
{xsol, ysol, xsola, ysola}
```

The reason to assign the output of `FindRoot` is to use it in fixed point calculations, similarly to this question: [wrong use of _?NumberQ?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/) The equations represented in the MWE as `D[(x-1)^2]==0` etc will be solutions of integrals, often not in closed form, depending on parameters. `Integrate` has trouble with them and `NIntegrate` does not work because of the non-numeric parameters.

A related question [More issues Integrate, NIntegrate, FindRoot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89797/) suggests using `==` under `FindRoot`, which I am already doing.

More background in case anyone is curious and has too much time on their hands: a bigger piece of code (possibly with errors) into which I am trying to fit the `FindRoot` is

```
Clear[d, s, vi, vj, vlb, mui, muj, pi, pj, profit, ci, cj, pbr, \
pisol, pjsol, pis, pjs]
$Assumptions = 
  0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs} < 1/2 && 0 < {mui, muj, vlb, vi, vj} < 1 &&
    0 <= {ci, cj} < 1;
vlb[pi_, pj_] = 
 1 + pi - pj - 
  Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s]; ci = 0.; cj = 0.05; mui = 0.5; muj = 0.5; 
d[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_] = 
 mui*(1 - Max[pi, vlb[pi, pj]]) + 
  mui*Integrate[vi - pi + pj, {vi, Max[pi, 0], Max[pi, vlb[pi, pj]]}, 
    Assumptions -> 0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs} < 1/2 && 0 < {vlb} < 1] +
   muj*Integrate[(1 - Max[pi, vj - pj + pi]), {vj, 0, vlb[pj, pis]}, 
    Assumptions -> 0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs} < 1/2 && 0 < {vlb} < 1]; 
profit[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_, c_] = (pi - c)*d[pi, pj, s, pis]; 
pbr[pj_Real?Positive, s_Real?Positive, pis_Real?Positive, 
  c_Real?Positive] = 
 NArgMax[{profit[pi, pj, s, pis, c], c < pi < 1/2}, pi]
pisol[s_Real?Positive] := 
 pi /. FindRoot[{pbr[pj, s, pis, ci] == pi, pbr[pi, s, pjs, cj] == pj,
    pi == pis, 
     pj == pjs}, {{pi, 0.3}, {pj, 0.4}, {pis, 0.35}, {pjs, 0.45}}]
pjsol[s_Real?Positive] := 
 pj /. FindRoot[{pbr[pj, s, pis, ci] == pi, pbr[pi, s, pjs, cj] == pj,
     pi == pis, 
   pj == pjs}, {{pi, 0.3}, {pj, 0.4}, {pis, 0.35}, {pjs, 0.45}}]
pisol[0.25]
Plot[{pisol[s], pjsol[s]}, {s, 0., 0.5}](*Does not solve in 45 min. *)
```

I have tried to modify this to use derivatives instead of `NArgMax`:

```
(*Using derivatives instead of NArgMax*)
Clear[d, s, vi, vj, vlb, \
mui, muj, pi, pj, profit, ci, cj, pfoc, pisol, pjsol, pis, pjs]
$Assumptions = 
  0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs} < 1/2 && 0 < {mui, muj, vlb, vi, vj} < 1 &&
    0 <= {ci, cj} < 1;
vlb[pi_, pj_] = 
 1 + pi - pj - 
  Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s]; ci = 0.; cj = 0.05; mui = 0.5; muj = 0.5; 
d[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_] = 
 mui*(1 - Max[pi, vlb[pi, pj]]) + 
  mui*Integrate[vi - pi + pj, {vi, Max[pi, 0], Max[pi, vlb[pi, pj]]}, 
    Assumptions -> 0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs} < 1/2 && 0 < {vlb} < 1] +
   muj*Integrate[(1 - Max[pi, vj - pj + pi]), {vj, 0, vlb[pj, pis]}, 
    Assumptions -> 0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs} < 1/2 && 0 < {vlb} < 1];
d[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25]
profit[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_, c_] = (pi - c)*d[pi, pj, s, pis]; 
pfoc[pi_Real?Positive, pj_Real?Positive, s_Real?Positive, 
  pis_Real?Positive, c_Real?Positive] = 
 D[profit[pi, pj, s, pis, c], pi]
pisol[s_Real?Positive] := 
 pi /. FindRoot[{pfoc[pi, pj, s, pis, ci] == 0, 
    pfoc[pj, pi, s, pjs, cj] == 0, pi == pis, 
    pj == pjs}, {{pi, 0.3}, {pj, 0.4}, {pis, 0.35}, {pjs, 0.45}}]
pjsol[s_Real?Positive] := 
 pj /. FindRoot[{pfoc[pi, pj, s, pis, ci] == 0, 
    pfoc[pj, pi, s, pjs, cj] == 0, pi == pis, 
    pj == pjs}, {{pi, 0.3}, {pj, 0.4}, {pis, 0.35}, {pjs, 0.45}}]
pisol[0.25]
Plot[{pisol[s], pjsol[s]}, {s, 0., 0.5}]
```

`Integrate` was very slow on the `Max` of linear functions. The result should be piecewise quadratic and can be done by hand. `NIntegrate` gives errors about non-numerical boundaries even when replacing the symbolic boundary by a number:

```
Clear[d, s, vi, vj, vlb, mui, muj, pi, pj, profit, ci, cj, pfoc, \
pisol, pjsol, pis, pjs]
$Assumptions = 
  0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs} < 1/2 && 0 < {mui, muj, vlb, vi, vj} < 1 &&
    0 <= {ci, cj} < 1;
vlb[pi_, pj_] = 
 1 + pi - pj - 
  Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s]; ci = 0.; cj = 0.05; mui = 0.5; muj = 0.5; 
d[pi_Real?Positive, pj_Real?Positive, s_Real?Positive, 
  pis_Real?Positive] = 
 mui*(1 - Max[pi, vlb[pi, pj]]) + 
  mui*NIntegrate[
    vi - pi + pj, {vi, Max[pi, 0], Max[pi, vlb[pi, pj]]}] + 
  muj*NIntegrate[(1 - Max[pi, vj - pj + pi]), {vj, 0, vlb[pj, pis]}];
d[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25]
```

yields `vi = Max[0.,pi] is not a valid limit of integration`.

I have encountered similar problems many times before in Mathematica when trying to find fixed points. I gave up each time after many days of trying, so I do not anticipate a solution now.

As I see it, there is a conflict between Mathematica constraints: `Integrate` does not work (for no good reason) or takes hours, but `NIntegrate` requires numeric arguments. For all parameters, numeric values would be fine, but for the candidate fixed point (`pis` in the above code), the maximization or derivative-taking has to happen before setting `pis==pi`.

One way may be to solve using all possible guesses of `pis` before `pis==pi`, maybe by `FunctionInterpolation`, but this again is too slow.

Comment: Why are you using `:=` and not `=`? `Clear[x, y, xsola, ysola]; {xsola, ysola} = {x, y} /. FindRoot[{D[(x - 1)^2] == 0, D[(y - 2)^2] == 0}, {{x, 0.3}, {y, 0.4}}]`

Comment: @J.M. is in limbo I am trying to use this in a bigger piece of code where `=` creates errors of non-numeric values: `FindRoot: The function value {<<1>>} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} at {pi,pj} = {0.3`,0.4`}` I can expand the MWE to illustrate if my explanation is unclear. Basically, replace `(x-1)` by `x-a` and try to plot on `{a,0,1}`.

Comment: That looks like a case where `FindRoot[]` is not able to come up with a solution, so of course a replacement rule does not get produced.

Comment: Could you clarify? `FindRoot` does find solutions in my MWE and the real code. Just assigning these solutions seems problematic. I can assign these element by element and plot just fine, but it seems inelegant. I can live with not assigning these as vectors - one of Mathematica's little mysteries why vector assignment does not work.

Comment: As I already said, your use of `:=` is precisely the problem. Recall that `:=` does *not* immediately evaluate its RHS, so of course there is a mismatch between `{xsola, ysola}` and `ReplaceAll[{x, y}, FindRoot[(* stuff *)]]`. Otherwise, the only way an assignment with `=` (instead of `:=`) will fail is if `FindRoot[]` itself cannot find a solution. Perhaps this is a time to reconsider the design of your actual code.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Comment: @MichaelE2 which part of the question or answers is related? Missing semicolons, stack trace, `findBadSets`?

Comment: `findBadSets` will help identify the source of the message. Since only one (complete) line of the MWE is needed to reproduce the problem and the others are irrelevant, it seemed there was some difficulty locating the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offending line with the `SetDelayed::shape` error is:

```
{xsola, ysola} := {x, y} /. 
  FindRoot[{D[(x - 1)^2] == 0, 
    D[(y - 2)^2] == 0}, {{x, 0.3}, {y, 0.4}}]
```

The `FullForm` of the offending line looks like `SetDelay[List[..], ReplaceAll[..]]`. The two arguments to `SetDelayed[]` should be lists of the same shape, if the first argument is a list.  In this case, the second argument is not a list at all.  When the first argument is a list, `SetDelayed` makes a series of definitions, one for each element in the list.  The value for each comes from the corresponding element in the second argument. (It does this recursively down nest lists.)  With `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` as @J.M. recommended, the `ReplaceAll` argument will evaluate to a list.

Given this tidbit:

> I am trying to use this in a bigger piece of code where = creates errors of non-numeric values.

It sounds like the problem is to delay the call of `FindRoot` until certain conditions are met.
It might be better to refactor the code so that those conditions can be passed in functions calls.

Not knowing more, something like the following might be a quick workaround:

```
ClearAll[getSola];
getSola[] :=
  {xsola, ysola} = {x, y} /. 
    FindRoot[{D[(x - 1)^2] == 0, 
      D[(y - 2)^2] == 0}, {{x, 0.3}, {y, 0.4}}];
getSola[]
{xsol, ysol, xsola, ysola}
(*
  {1., 2.}
  {1., 2., 1., 2.}
*)
```

Also,  one could hold up evaluation as follows depending on a condition, or give an error if the condition was not satisfied:

```
ClearAll[getSola];
SetAttributes[getSola, HoldAll];
getSola[vars_, cond_] /; TrueQ@cond :=
  vars = {x, y} /. 
    FindRoot[{D[(x - a)^2] == 0, 
      D[(y - b)^2] == 0}, {{x, 0.3}, {y, 0.4}}];

getSola[{xsola, ysola}, VectorQ[{a, b}, NumericQ]]
```

If `a` and `b` are numeric, `FindRoot` is called and the variables are set;
otherwise, nothing is done.  `getSol[]` is similar to `ConditionalExpression[]`, except that `ConditionalExpression[]` evaluates to `Undefined` when the condition is `False` and `getSola[]` remains unevaluated.

Probably the first alternative is better. At least it fits better with how I imagine the bigger code is organized.  But I could easily be wrong.

Comment: I didn't want to guess at what monster the OP actually has, but your proposal is surely reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Long comment about an important side-issue in one of the examples: In one case, the assumptions are defined wrong: `a < {x, y, z} < b` does not translate into three inequalities. One can refactor with `VectorLess` or `Thread`:

```
Clear[d, s, vi, vj, vlb, mui, muj, pi, pj, profit, ci, cj, pfoc, \
pisol, pjsol, pis, pjs]
($Assumptions = 
   Flatten@{Thread[0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs} < 1/2], 
     Thread[0 < {mui, muj, vlb, vi, vj} < 1], 
     Thread[0 <= {ci, cj} < 1]};
  vlb[pi_, pj_] = 1 + pi - pj - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s]; ci = 0.; cj = 0.05; 
  mui = 0.5; muj = 0.5;
  d[pi_Real?Positive, pj_Real?Positive, s_Real?Positive, 
    pis_Real?Positive] = 
   mui*(1 - Max[pi, vlb[pi, pj]]) + 
    mui*Integrate[
      vi - pi + pj, {vi, Max[pi, 0], Max[pi, vlb[pi, pj]]}] + 
    muj*Integrate[(1 - Max[pi, vj - pj + pi]), {vj, 0, 
       vlb[pj, pis]}];
  d[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.162937, 0.545695}  *)
```

Note that exact (symbolic) solvers sometimes run into trouble with inexact floating-point parameters like `ci = 0.1`.  Here it does not, so we're lucky.  However, if it did, then one could do the following (and it's faster by a factor of 1/3000 if you have to call `d[]` multiple times): If you define `d[]` before you define the parameters, then the integration will be done with exact symbols just as quickly; and `d[]` returns the same result.  Then you don't have to worry about round-off error causing `Integrate` to choke.

Comment: Thank you for the assumption threading - I did not know it and was unaware of the issue, so could not even ask the question. The floating point warning messages with exact solvers I have seen before, but in this case did not notice - thanks for correcting that as well!

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu You're welcome!